# Cant find asp.net worker process

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-7.5

I am trying to debug my asp.net project in VS 2010 but I don't see w3wp.exe anywhere when I try to attach it to a process. Unfortunately when I hit the debug button, the app tries to build and deploy and hangs indefinitely.
I am able to run the application by directly pointing to the hostname in a browser.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Have you checked the 'show processes from all users' box? I think w3wp.exe will be running under 'network service' or similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope you have your application hosted in IIS. Folllow the below mentioned steps.

1. Open the Inetmgr window.
2. Browse the your application again from IIS.
3. Click Tools => Attach process and this time you can find the worker process
   .

---

### Alternative

Make sure to select the below highlighted options.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you selected the checkbox `Show processes in all sessions`?